# json parse method in unity

Tags: json, unity-game-engine

want to parse json in Unity but I don't know how.

The json content that I want to parse.

```
{
"route": {
    "trafast": [
            "path": [
                [
                    0,
                    0
                ],

                [
                    1,
                    1
                ],
                [
                    1,
                    2
                ]
            ]
```

]}}

I have to parse the contents of the "path".

This is the code I was writing.

```
    public static T[] drivingFromJson<T>(string json)
{
    drivingWrapper<T> wrapper = UnityEngine.JsonUtility.FromJson<drivingWrapper<T>>(json);
    return wrapper.trafast;
}

[Serializable]
private class drivingWrapper<T>
{
    public T[] trafast;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class DrivingTrafast
{
    public PathData[] trafast;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class PathData
{
    public TrafastPath[] path;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class TrafastPath
{
    public string[] tp;
}
```

I have no idea how to get the arrangement in the "path."
Tell me about the description and method.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Besides ... this isn't even correct JSON afaik ... you would additionally need `{ }` around `"path ..."`

Comment: "path..." It was a sign that there were many values between.

Comment: Does path mean double arrangement?

Comment: `path` is a field **name** ... just like `trafast`, `route` or `xyz`. Is says nothing about the underlying field **type** ... But as said currently this is no correct JSON. See [Nested Arrays in JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) you need `{ }` around each instance of a nested **type**

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can not use generics (`T`) in [`JsonUtility`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html):

> **Supported Types**
>
> The API supports any `MonoBehaviour`-subclass,
>   `ScriptableObject`-subclass, or plain `class`/`struct` with the
>   `[Serializable]` attribute. The object you pass in is fed to the
>   [standard Unity serializer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html) for processing, so the same rules and
>   limitations apply as they do in the Inspector; only **fields** are
>   serialized, and types like `Dictionary<T>` are not supported.
>
> Passing other types directly to the API, for example primitive types
>   or arrays, is not currently supported. For now you will need to wrap
>   such types in a class or struct of some sort.

and from the [Unity Serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html)

> **How to ensure a custom class can be serialized**
>
> Ensure it:
>
> - Has the `[Serializable]` attribute
> - Is not `abstract`
> - Is not `static`
> - **Is not generic**, though it may inherit from a generic class

---

Then you JSON structure isn't valid ... it should be something like

```
{
    "route" : {
        "trafast": [
            {
                "path" : [
                    [0,0], [1,1], [1,2]
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

wrapping the elements of `trafast` with `{ }` (see [JSON Data Types](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp) and [Nested Arrays in JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp)).

---

And finally you need the c# layout that mirrors this JSON structure and its according types.

You can use e.g. [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) as a start point  automatically generating the according c# layout for a given JSON. You will need to make all classes `[Serializable]` and use proper **fields** instead of properties:

```
[Serializable]
public class RootObject
{
    public Route route;
}

[Serializable]
public class Route
{
    public List<Trafast> trafast;
}

[Serializable]
public class Trafast
{
    public List<List<int>> path;
}
```

---

Now you can use

```
var json = "{\"route\" : {\"trafast\": [{\"path\" : [[0,0], [1,1], [1,2] ] } ] } }";

var rootObject = JsonUtility.FromJson<RootObject>(json);
```

Comment: var RootObject = JohnsonUtility.FromJson<RootObject>(www.text);
Debug.Log("drivingTrafast : " + RootObject.route.trafast[0].path[0][0]);
What did I do wrong when I didn't get the price?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the above answer but it was not resolved.

So while I was looking at Google, I saw "Newtonsoft.Json" and tested it.

```
[Serializable]
public class RootObject
{
    public Route route;
}

[Serializable]
public class Route
{
    public List<Trafast> trafast;
}

[Serializable]
public class Trafast
{
    public List<List<string>> path;
}
```

After making a class like above,

```
rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(www.text);
Debug.Log("drivingTrafast : " + rootObject.route.trafast[0].path[i][j]);
```

And I was able to bring JSON.